# Parsing large tcpdump files in python

Tags: python, wireshark, tcpdump

I have a large tcpdump capture ( with > 1gb of data in a .dump file) which I would like to parse to get some statistics like the number of different IPs involved in sending traffic, etc. I would like to know if there is a clean way of accessing such data in the binary trace file through python? 
The way I tried doing it is by running
`tcpdump -r something.dump > myfile.out`
And then try to parse myfile.out with python code to get the data i want. But the command above is taking forever to complete and would like to use a better way of doing this.

Edit: Wireshark runs out of memory while trying to open the file.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [`dpkt` module](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/). It should be able to parse the pcap file on demand.  Jon Oberheide has a great [blog post showing how you can access the parsed representation of packets](http://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2008/10/15/dpkt-tutorial-2-parsing-a-pcap-file/) within a pcap packet capture file.